# вывод чисел без e в dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

работаю в jupyter notebook. 
в одном из столбцов получаются значения 3.400000e-02, 2.662840e+01, 1.355128e+08 и т.д.

Как мне сделать так, чтобы все цифры в датафрейме выводились в обычном виде?

Answer (score 2):

Поможет команда:

```
pd.options.display.float_format ='{:,.3f}'.format
```

Где цифра 3 означает число разрядов после запятой