# pandas: количество знаков после запятой

Tags: python, pandas, float

Решил рассчитать процент дохода от источника относительно общей суммы. В итоге есть значения вроде 0.0052 или 0.0007, но в столбце они автоматически обрезаются до 0.00. Пытался сделать так:

```
sources_revenue['ratio'] = (sources_revenue['revenue'] / sources_revenue['revenue'].sum() * 100).apply('{:.4f}'.format)`
```

, но так получаются строки.

А `apply(lambda x: float(x))`, `astype(float)` и `to_numeric(sources_revenue.ratio)` снова округляют до двух знаков...

Comment: Вы путаете округление и отображение. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69615293/number-of-digits-after-decimal-point-in-pandas

Comment: Странные вещи творятся. Решил проблему переименованием файла. Сменил название и сразу значения стали выводиться без округления.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй так:

```
pd.options.display.float_format ='{:,.4f}'.format
```

Мне помогло. Взяла отсюда [ссылка на ответ похожий запрос в stackoverflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1095460/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-e-%D0%B2-dataframe)